# MySQL 's 'secure-file-priv' not allowing load data infile, even from the allocated safe folder

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to upload a large .csv file into a database (not on a server, just on my local computer only for my use) on MySQL.  I have been having the **Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement** error thrown.

I put my .csv file into the specified 'safe' folder (C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads) specified in the 'my' file, but it kept giving me the same error.  Every solution I've seen has been using that folder destination and since that doesn't work can anyone help me get around or turn off the secure-file-priv option?

Here is my code in case wanted:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\my-file.csv'
INTO TABLE my-table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) for LOAD DATA INFILE:

> The file name must be given as a literal string. On Windows, specify backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes. The character_set_filesystem system variable controls the interpretation of the file name.

```mysql
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/my-file.csv"
INTO TABLE my-table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: You can improve the quality of your answer by also adding a corrected copy of their code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Using forward slashes instead of backslashes (even on Windows machine) fixed it for me.